# how to implement parallel programming in Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

which libraries we need for parallel programming in JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

You simply start new threads, using the `Runnable` interface (or a lambda function, in Java 8) with the `Thread` constructor. Here's a really, really basic example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    System.out.println("I'm in a different thread from the other code in this example");
});
t.start();
```

Then, of course, you have to handle all the issues around concurrency, which involves things like the `synchronized` keyword, various things (perhaps) from [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and its child packages, etc.

There's a [Java tutorial on this here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: Since the asker is "new in Java", I don't think this will suffice to him... I believe this needs close votes, not answers

Comment: @JanDvorak: animuson appears to agree. :-)